# SQl not connected

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-rest-framework, mysql-notifier

I have sql installed but then also its showing me this.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'mahima'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

This is from my settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dev_jrc_api',
        'USER':'mahima',
        'PASSWORD':'****',
        'HOST':'192.168.0.37',
        'PORT':'3307',
        'OPTIONS':{'init_command':"SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"}
    }
}
```

Comment: That is clearly a MySQL Connection string; it won't work with SQL Server.

Comment: I think your password is wrong! Refer: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-changing-password.aspx/

Comment: @Larnu can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @Shri Hari actually I have to got a password from my company, I have just mentioned here with this***

Comment: Well if you're using SQL Server the default port is 1433 and the MySQL engine won't work. What RDBMS are you *really* using here?

Comment: @Larnu used MYSQL

Comment: actually its a part of searchable dropdown list that I made with the help of a youtube video,did exactly what was given in there but then also its not working

Comment: Then you've tagged the wrong RDBMS; (Microsoft) SQL Server and (Oracle's) MySQL are completely different products.

Comment: this is the link of that video https://youtu.be/Eu-I3PnIx5g

Comment: @Larnu how to tag the right server?

Comment: Using the [edit] feature @MahimaChandwani, though I have already done this for you almost an hour ago.